# pager in ie8 taking extra space

Tags: css

My pager looking fine in other browsers but ie it takes extra space.

others browsers:

[image]

ie8
[image]

Html code:

```
<ul class="pager"><li class="pager-current first">1</li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 2" href="/mi-mn-library">2</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 3" href="/mi-mn-library">3</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 4" href="/mi-mn-library">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

My css:

```
.item-list .pager {
clear: both;
text-align: center;
}
.item-list .pager li {
background-image: none;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: i think this code is correct. maybe other codes make this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css" link rel="stylesheet" > 
      .item-list .pager li{
       padding:.2em;

        }
        </style>
<![endif]-->
```